Merging multiple road layers into one (like on topo maps) using QGIS
I have two shapefiles in QGIS containing polylines. One has 7m wide lines and the other has 5m wide lines. They currently exist on different layers, making intersections look like overpasses.
How do I join them together to make them look like branches off of a main road instead of bridges?

Polylines are 1D, they have length but no width.  Do you have parallel polylines in each layer, do you have polygons instead, or do you actually have polylines and are symbolizing them to make them look 7m & 5m wide?

Merge into a single virtual layer.  Use symbol levels https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#follow-along-ordering-symbol-levels

I think a picture would help clarify what you are asking.

Processing Toolbox --> Merge Vector Layers;
You would have an attribute in the table showing the source of the data. You could use this to categorize your symbology.
Otherwise copy all of the features into the other shapefile. Formatting of the copied features will be lost.

Open Attribute Table

Select all Features
Copy selected features


Open second Attribute Table

Turn on editing mode
Paste selected features



Since the issue seems to be the visualization you could try changing that, instead of merging.

Thank you for the help. To clarify, I need to have two different road widths formatted separately, while still having them join neatly.

@Sprock3t Such clarifications are best used to improve your question  by editing it so that it can be re-opened for additional answers.
